# How to copy the data between different mongo servers in incremental model like once in a day in mongodb without using replication?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I want to copy the data to my independent server in incremental model in once in a day from the other production primary server(Actually this is one replication setup primary,secondary,arbitry).For example i copied the data today then if i copy tomorrow i should get only updated data only.

how we can achieve this requirement?

If incremental process won't work we can go for

a) db.cloneDatabase();

b)db.copyDatabase();

c)export and import

If we use these commands will they acquired write lock on primary?
I need best suggestion

Comment: How do you know what's "new" since yesterday?

Comment: I need solution to solve this problem.If we take replication that info stores in oplogs.Some thing like that i want maintain time stamp like how in replication.Is there any other way  to do it ?

Here my problem is making some reports those taking much time so i want to copy the data to my other server.so no effect on my production site.If i copy the whole data to my independent server every day again it creates performance problem.so i want update the data to independent server like how it has done in replication.

Do not we have solution for this ?
Do am thinking in wrong way ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik-oss/

But it has implemented in java and scala.But i am not aware of scala if everything is available in java it would be better.